# Raspberry Pi won't log in

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, login

I'm trying to log in to my Raspberry Pi with the default Pi / Raspberry login but for some reason it isn't working. When it asks for 'raspberrypi login:' I type in 'pi' and press enter. Nothing happens for a while then it asks for the login again, like this:

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 raspberrypi tty1

raspberrypi login: pi

Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 raspberrypi tty1

raspberrypi login: pi

Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 raspberrypi tty1

raspberrypi login:
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for that behavior would be an empty file `/etc/nologin` which prohibits logins on the system for all users beside root. For this problem the solution would be to delete the file `/etc/nologin`

It would be very helpful to see few last lines of

```
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/syslog
```

Comment: A further one - which is not possible on an RPi that is just sat there idly waiting for you to log in is _extreme_ system load.  If you have set the RPi to do something intensely processor or memory intensive it is possible to get to a state that the system does not have the memory or processor cycles to allow the login to complete in the time allowed for it (which I think is around 60 seconds).  In some cases - where the system has run out of main / swap memory the Out Of Memory Killer might kill off the errant process that has eaten all the memory but it does take time to kick in...

Comment: I've plugged the micro SD card into a laptop and could not find any folders called 'etc' or files called 'nologin' inside it , only a folder called 'overlays' and a bunch of files. Sorry if this is a stupid mistake.

Comment: if you are using windows, it won't like multiple partitions on one sd card and hence you only see the boot partition. but directory `etc` is situated in the root partition `/` (see http://superuser.com/questions/975900/sd-card-second-partition-not-recognized )

Comment: I have checked and there are no files called /etc/nologin. Would formatting the card and reinstalling noobs work?